# PC controlled irrigation system

Tags: watering, sprinkler-system, drip-system, irrigation

I am investigating the use of a PC to control my yard irrigation system. The research that I've done has only revealed one system with the (unfortunate) name of Irritrol.

Have you used your PC to control your yard irrigation system? If so, how did you do it?

I am considering hobbling something together with an X10 controller and writing some software to control it but don't want to dive into that if it's already been done...

Comment: Well, it's also known among farming circles as Irritation... one of many puns on the truths of life.

Comment: I just talk to Irritrol today 7-15-16, to replace my broken unit.They said they discontinued the pc controller last year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A company called Irrigation Caddy makes a great product that runs on an internal network, and even has mods for remote offsite management depending on your router and web skills.

http://www.irrigationcaddy.com/

Answer (score 9):

If you want to write software probably you are looking for customized solutions, you have imagination and you don't mind  to do it yourself.

I suggest you try search with google: Arduino + Watering
( for example look at this document: [THE GARDUINO GARDEN CONTROLLER](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj5i92S2PfNAhVBsRQKHTfBAIYQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26pid%3Dsites%26srcid%3DaXZhbmZtLmNvbXxkaWNhc3xneDo2YTMzZmUwYTFkMDc0ZTJi&usg=AFQjCNEucqtpucltvYoZEATVQnzSLCZVqA&sig2=m9msV-1kH2Vv-qQlhbiC_Q)

It is a simple open-source platform with which many hobbyists have already ventured and you can find a community willing to help.

Comment: Thanks Ronda, that's a great read. Not quite what I'm looking for but very close and inspiring.

Comment: Add relay drivers and you'll be able to run standard servo sprinkler valves...

Comment: Document Not Found :-(

Comment: @dakab thank you for the comment; I've just updated the link in the answer

Answer (score 5):

If you're techie enough to mess with code, feel free to use mine. I built an arduino-based solar powered one that cues off soil moisture levels instead of timing.

https://github.com/kolosy/irrigation

Comment: Used with low voltage, latching solenoids on the sprinkler control valves means no power draw needed to keep the valves on. Self-contained solar sprinkler system, I like it.

Comment: thanks! yeah- i use a latching solenoid for this. works quite well for my roof deck, and the battery is charged in ~2 hours of sunlight.

Answer (score 3):

I have used two wi-fi controllers for our irrigation from 
http://www.hottimesoftware.com/wifi-time-control.htm and are happy with the results. Uses the Raspberry Pi to operate the solenoids and can be set to auto or manual functions. I can now control from anywhere in the world with my smart phone.
[image]

Comment: In the Raspi theme, there's also OpenSprinkler: https://rayshobby.net/ospi/ which I'm currently looking at. This house has an electro-mechanical timer. Simple no-nonsense & reliable, but if I add a soaker then I'll need different day schedules for the different zones. A Raspi solution has a lot going for it...